# Is there a way to obtain infinite webpage with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that we can obtain infinite web pages that can be scrollable to down and right? Is there a way to obtain same effect(with ajax requests and without flash or silverlight) that can be scrollable to every direction?
IF there is an example of this i want it :D.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the point of this kind of page?

Comment: got some bad things on your mind ? ;)

Comment: Example of this can be seen on those wallpaper sites (4walled?) that let you scroll continuously down and it constantly loads new images for you. You'll likely have to modify code you find to do the other directions.

Comment: something like this? http://rumpetroll.com/

Comment: @Nik, I always hated from comments like this. It is not a positive comment, so i am replying as the comment desires, it is none of your business.@Dmitriy Naumov. i am not sure :D. @Tony and @Prescott, those are not exactly what i want

Comment: Haha, ok, was just curious. I've never heard of this before, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, why wouldn't there be?  example:

http://maps.google.com

:)

Basically it's the same logic as loading content when you get to the bottom, it just requires a moveable div in a wrapper and for you to check the bounds in every direction.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

*EDIT* Just saw you want to go in every direction so this does not apply.